# How do I get id for a certain data of mysql in php?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to get id of a data in php to update it in my database. I have tried a lot of things I found online but could not solve the issue. Here is ALL the code for editing.

This is where the posts are displayed but I don't know how to get id for each post so that people can edit/can be edited on mysql

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect ('localhost', 'root', '', '');

mysqli_select_db ($link, 'CodersHome');

?>

<?php
session_start ();
if( !isset($_SESSION['username']))
header('location:../login.php');
 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CodersHome Agenda</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="../tabimg.png">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="profile/profile.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../navbar/navbar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="agendacss/agendap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="agendacss/agendacard.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/4.1.1/normalize.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/d1341f9b7a.js"></script>
    <script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/darkmode-js@1.5.5/lib/darkmode-js.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.14.0/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script src="agendatabs.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>
<?php include '../navbar/navbar.html' ?>
  <body>


    <div id="page-container">
      <div id="content-wrap">

        <ul class="tab">
          <li><a href="#" class="tablinks active" onclick="openCity(event, 'agenda')"><strong>Agenda</strong></a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'createagenda')"><strong>Crea Agenda</strong></a></li>
        </ul>
<br>
    <div id="agenda" class="tabcontent">
      <div class="welcome">
        <h1 class="weltitle">Agenda 1er D</h1>
     </div>
     <br><hr><br>
      <?php
      $result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM agenda");

      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  {

      //echo $row["title"];
      //echo $row["description"];
      //echo $row["datef"];


      ?>

      <?php $i=0; ?>
      <div class="row">
      <div class="column">
      <div class="card">
    <?php echo $row["description"]; ?>
    <?php echo $row["datef"]; ?>  &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <?php echo $row["inserter"]; ?> <?php if($_SESSION['username'] == 'admin') { include('eddel.php');

    } ?> <br>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
      <br>
      <?php
      $i++;
      }
      ?>

    </div>
```

Here you can see where I try to Update.

```
<?php

session_start ();

$link = mysqli_connect ('localhost', 'root', '', '');

mysqli_select_db ($link, '');


if($link === false){
   die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$title = $_POST ['title'];
$desc = $_POST ['editor1'];
$date1 = $_POST ['date1'];
$inserter = $_SESSION['username'];

$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM agenda");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  {

//echo $row["title"];
//echo $row["description"];
//echo $row["datef"];
$i=0;
}
$sql = "UPDATE agenda SET title = $title, description = $desc, datef = $date1, inserter = $inserter WHERE id = $row[id]; ";
  $i++;
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
header("Refresh:0; url=agenda.php");
}

?>

<?php
if( !isset($_SESSION['username']))
header('location:../login.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>CodersHome Agenda</title>
   <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="../tabimg.png">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="profile/profile.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../navbar/navbar.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="agendacss/agendap.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="agendacss/agendacard.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/4.1.1/normalize.min.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/d1341f9b7a.js"></script>
   <script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/darkmode-js@1.5.5/lib/darkmode-js.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.14.0/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
   <script src="agendatabs.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
 </head>
<?php include '../navbar/navbar.html' ?>
 <body>


<div class="welcome2">
   <p class="weltitle">Edita Una Agenda</p>
</div>
<br><hr><br>
           <form class="agfrm" action="agendaedit.php" method="post">

             <div class="form-group">

               <label>Title</label> <br> <br>
               <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" required><br> <br>

             </div>

             <div class="form-group">

               <label>Description</label> <br> <br>

               <textarea name="editor1" required></textarea>
                    <script>
                            CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
                    </script> <br> <br>
             </div>

           <label>Date</label> <br> <br>
           <input type="date" id="date1" name="date1"
                  value="2020-02-25"
                  min="2020-01-01" max="2021-12-31" required> <br>
                  <br>
       <button type="submit" class="homepbtn1">Sumbit</button>


       </form>

   </div>


     </div>


 </body>

</html>

<?php include '../Footer/index.html'?>
```

I want to update a data in a table. I also have the id assgined for each row but i dont know how to get the id to edit the exact row of the table.

Also here is a live demo of where post is created and diplayed.

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
body {
background-color: white;
  height: 96vh;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


.welcome {
  border: 2px solid black;
  color: #7d3caf;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  font-weight: 5em;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic', sans-serif;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.welcome:hover
{
  border: 1px solid #6747c7 ;
  background-color: #6747c7;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic', sans-serif;

   }


.weltitle {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
 .weldis {
   font-family: 'Century Gothic', sans-serif;
   text-align: center;
 }
.gtac {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: monospace;
}
.gtacl {
  text-align: center;
}

.gtac1:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: black;
  border:  2px solid black;
}

.lbtn {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  transition: 0.6s ease
}

.lbtn:hover{
  background-color: #7a7979;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
}


.span1 {
  height: 40px;
}

.homepbtn1 {
  top: 50%;
  left: 80%;
  background-color: #36344d;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.homepbtn1:hover {
  background-color: #7a7979;
  color: white;
  background-color: #FF5A36;
    border-radius: 50px;

}

.btnmargin1 {
  height: 60px;
}

.btnmargin2 {
  height: 60px;
}

.extraspace {
  height: 6px;
}



.weltitle {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 36px;

}
 .weldis {
   font-family: 'Century Gothic', sans-serif;

 }

ul.tab {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Float the list items side by side */
ul.tab li {float: left;}

/* Style the links inside the list items */
ul.tab li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of links on hover */
ul.tab li a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
ul.tab li a:focus, .active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    -webkit-animation: fadeEffect 1s;
    animation: fadeEffect 1s;
}
div[class*="tabcontent"]:first-of-type {
    display: block;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeEffect {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeEffect {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

/* Dropdown Button */
.dbtn {
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.ddown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dcon {
  display: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dcon a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dcon a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.ddown:hover .dcon {display: block;}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.down:hover .dbtn {background-color: transparent;}

body {
background-color: white;
  height: 96vh;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


.welcome {
  border: 2px solid black;
  color: #7d3caf;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  font-weight: 5em;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic', sans-serif;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.welcome:hover
{
  border: 1px solid #6747c7 ;
  background-color: #6747c7;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic', sans-serif;

   }


.weltitle {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
 .weldis {
   font-family: 'Century Gothic', sans-serif;
   text-align: center;
 }
.gtac {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: monospace;
}
.gtacl {
  text-align: center;
}

.gtac1:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: black;
  border:  2px solid black;
}

.lbtn {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  transition: 0.6s ease
}

.lbtn:hover{
  background-color: #7a7979;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
}


.span1 {
  height: 40px;
}

.homepbtn1 {
  top: 50%;
  left: 80%;
  background-color: #36344d;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.homepbtn1:hover {
  background-color: #7a7979;
  color: white;
  background-color: #FF5A36;
    border-radius: 50px;

}

.btnmargin1 {
  height: 60px;
}

.btnmargin2 {
  height: 60px;
}

.extraspace {
  height: 6px;
}



.weltitle {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 36px;

}
 .weldis {
   font-family: 'Century Gothic', sans-serif;

 }

ul.tab {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Float the list items side by side */
ul.tab li {float: left;}

/* Style the links inside the list items */
ul.tab li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of links on hover */
ul.tab li a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
ul.tab li a:focus, .active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    -webkit-animation: fadeEffect 1s;
    animation: fadeEffect 1s;
}
div[class*="tabcontent"]:first-of-type {
    display: block;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeEffect {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeEffect {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect ('localhost', 'root', 'mywebsite1245', 'CodersHome');

mysqli_select_db ($link, 'CodersHome');

//$con = mysqli_connect ('Localhost', 'id12806518_root', 'mywebsite1245', 'id12806518_codershome');

//mysqli_select_db ($con, 'id12806518_codershome');
?>

<?php
session_start ();
if( !isset($_SESSION['username']))
header('location:../login.php');
 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CodersHome Agenda</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="../tabimg.png">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="profile/profile.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../navbar/navbar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="agendacss/agendap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="agendacss/agendacard.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/4.1.1/normalize.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/d1341f9b7a.js"></script>
    <script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/darkmode-js@1.5.5/lib/darkmode-js.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.14.0/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script src="agendatabs.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>
<?php include '../navbar/navbar.html' ?>
  <body>


    <div id="page-container">
      <div id="content-wrap">

        <ul class="tab">
          <li><a href="#" class="tablinks active" onclick="openCity(event, 'agenda')"><strong>Agenda</strong></a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'createagenda')"><strong>Crea Agenda</strong></a></li>
        </ul>
<br>
    <div id="agenda" class="tabcontent">
      <div class="welcome">
        <h1 class="weltitle">Agenda 1er D</h1>
     </div>
     <br><hr><br>
      <?php
      $result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM agenda");

      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  {

      //echo $row["title"];
      //echo $row["description"];
      //echo $row["datef"];


      ?>

      <?php $i=0; ?>
      <div class="row">
      <div class="column">
      <div class="card">
    <?php echo $row["description"]; ?>
    <?php echo $row["datef"]; ?>  &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <?php echo $row["inserter"]; ?> <?php if($_SESSION['username'] == 'admin') { include('eddel.php');

    } ?> <br>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
      <br>
      <?php
      $i++;
      }
      ?>

    </div>

    <div id="createagenda" class="tabcontent">


<div class="welcome2">
    <p class="weltitle">Crea Una Agenda</p>
</div>
<br><hr><br>
            <form class="agfrm" action="insert.php" method="post">

              <div class="form-group">

                <label>Title</label> <br> <br>
                <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" required><br> <br>

              </div>

              <div class="form-group">

                <label>Description</label> <br> <br>

                <textarea name="editor1" required></textarea>
                     <script>
                             CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
                     </script> <br> <br>
              </div>

            <label>Date</label> <br> <br>
            <input type="date" id="date1" name="date1"
                   value="2020-02-25"
                   min="2020-01-01" max="2021-12-31" required> <br>
                   <br>
        <button type="submit" class="homepbtn1">Sumbit</button>


        </form>

    </div>


      </div>


  </body>

</html>

  <?php include '../Footer/index.html'?>
```

Comment: String values need to be quoted or else they will be treated as column names, causing the query to fail. However, ssince you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur.**

Comment: I don't understand what rows are you trying to update.

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data...

Comment: ...and it will probably also help with the SQL syntax error you're almost certainly experiencing (but haven't reported).

Comment: Also, **never** get your web app to login to the database as root. Root can do whatever it likes,
so on top of the SQL injection vulnerabilities
this just leaves your database an open book for hackers.
Instead create a separate user account specifically for this application which has only the permissions it actually _needs_ in order to work properly.
Don't even use the root account as a shortcut during development or testing, because you need to test your account permissions as well - otherwise when you go live you might have unexpected errors relating to the user account setup.

Comment: P.S. If you only want to update one specific row of the agenda, then you need to send the ID of that row in your form data, along with all the other fields. e.g. you might have a hidden field in the HTML form which contains the ID of the row being edited. Then you could get it from $_POST["id"] and use it in your query. The way your code is written right now, it will try to (very inefficiently) update _all_ the rows in your table with the exact same data.

Comment: You are missing two steps I think: 1) in the list of items you need an "edit" link which takes you to a form for editing that single item. The link must contain the ID of the item on the querystring. Then the form you display for editing must contain the ID of the item (taken from the $_GET parameter) in a hidden field, so it can be passed again when the form is submitted. That way when the form is submitted you will know which item is being edited, and you can use the ID in your UPDATE query.

Answer (score -1):

The mistake you did was that you closed the while loop.Also, put the i outside for better approach.

```
$i=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  {

//echo $row["title"];
//echo $row["description"];
//echo $row["datef"];


$sql = "UPDATE agenda SET title = $title, description = $desc, datef = $date1, inserter = $inserter WHERE id = $row[id]; ";
  $i++;
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
header("Refresh:0; url=agenda.php");
}
}
?>
```

Comment: if it's really the OP's intention to update _all_ the rows in the table with the exact same values, then the `SELECT` and the `while` loop are actually pointless and inefficient. They could just remove the `WHERE` clause from the `UPDATE` query and execute it once, and it would update all rows. But looking at the wider context of the question I don't think this is the real intent - it would be a pretty strange thing to do anyway. OP, I think, wants to update one specific row, and is asking how to get the right ID of the row. The answer to that would be to pass it in from the HTML form.

Comment: How do I pass from the html file ? I also adeed the html file above

Comment: @AbisGamerYT use something like this 
`<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="<?php echo $var;?>" />`

Comment: Ok so I get the id in input and hide it right ? I tried that before but I don't know how to get that ECHO value that is hidden to my php file. Do I have to use `$bla = $_POST['id'];`

Comment: yes using post or get method but make sure there are conditions given if the post method has a NULL value, so you have to set the default value